# Elasticsearch pagination offset over nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, nested, offset

Is there any way to create pagination over nested objects in Elastisearch?
I the example data bellow I search offices (nested objects) and need to load only nested matches for requested pagination page.
For example, for `page 3` I need to load 4 items from offset 8 (office.3D, office.3E, office.4A, office.4B) + total count of matching nested items.

```
|-company.1
|   |-name
|   |-address
|   |-offices       __ __
|       |-office.1A   |
|-company.2           |
|   |-name            |
|   |-address         | page 1, size=4, offset=0
|   |-offices         |
|       |-office.2A   |
|       |-office.2B   |
|       |-office.2C __|__
|-company.3           |
|   |-name            |
|   |-address         |
|   |-offices         | page 2, size=4, offset=4
|       |-office.3A   |
|       |-office.3B   |
|       |-office.3C   |
|       |-office.3D __|__
|       |-office.3E   |
|-company.4           |
|   |-name            |
|   |-address         | page 3, size=4, offset=8
|   |-offices         |
|       |-office.4A   |
|       |-office.4B   |
|       |-office.4C __|__
|-company.5
...
```

Mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name":    { "type" : "keyword" }
            "address": { "type" : "keyword" }
            "offices": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "hash":   { "type": "keyword" },
                    "street": { "type": "keyword" },
                    "city":   { "type": "keyword" },
                    "zip":    { "type": "keyword" },
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that loading `page 2` (offset=4) should load root document `company.3` in the example above.
But Elasticsearch does not seem to support offset for nested fields, only for parent documents, or within nested objects for `inner_hits`.

I tried many queries and aggregates, but currently the only working solution is loading all matching nested objects along with root/parent document and loop over all of them until I reach offset for nested fields `0... nested offset`.
This is however very ineffective and even with allowing only maximum 500 pages (20 items per page size, means 10.000 default ES limit) I still may hit memory limits.
Database has up to 2 mil. records of root documents, and 600k nested office records.

Currently I use following query - example:

```
{
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: {
          0: {
            nested: {
              path: office
              inner_hits: { size: 20 }
              query: {
                bool: {
                  must: {
                    0: {
                      wildcard: {
                        office.city: Bratislava*
                      }
    }}}}}}}}}
    aggregations: {
      cnt-total: {
        nested: {
          path: office
        aggs: {
          cnt-matching: {
            filter: {
              bool: {
                must: {
                  0: {
                    wildcard: {
                      office.city: Bratislava*
                    }
    }}}}}}}}}
}
```

This will give me correct total number of matching nested documents.
But then I must loop over all loaded parent documents and calculate nested offset via script.
Is there more effective way to do this?

Comment: I think this not possible. Look [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filtering-sorting-and-paginate-nested-object-list/279078/2?u=rabbit_br)

Comment: @rabbitbr I am suspecting that too ... it's just confusing, that ES provides so many ways to aggregate, scrolled views etc .. that I am not sure whether I missed something. Thank you for your comment.